# Firestore security rules are not behaving as expected

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to perform the following write -

```
guard let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {fatalError()}

        let firstName = "firstName"
        let lastName = "lastName"
        let userName = "userName"
        let uid = userid

        let userInfo = [firstName:firstNameTextField.text!,
                        lastName:lastNameTextField.text!,
                        userName:userNameTextField.text!,
                        uid:userid]

        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userid).setData(userInfo) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToFeed", sender: self)
            }
        }
```

These are my security rules -

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /users/{userid} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow create: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;

    }
  }
}
```

This write is being denied when performed through Xcode simulator with the error - "Missing or insufficient permissions."

However, when I try to build the same document on Firestore rules simulator, it is being allowed.

Additionally, I also tried to modify that rule to this

```
match /users/{userid} {
  allow create: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid &&
userid == request.auth.uid
}
```

In the above case it is being denied both by Xcode simulator as well as Firestore simulator.

What am I doing wrong?

A few clarifications -

1. The write happens perfectly when rules are modified to make it an open database.
2. The documents structure looks like this -

```
let userInfo = [firstName:firstNameTextField.text!,
                      lastName:lastNameTextField.text!,
                      userName:userNameTextField.text!,
                      uid:userid]
```

Comment: If you remove the security rules, does it do exactly what you want?  What does the resulting document look like that you expect to be added?  (BTW your modified rule uses `&` where it should have probably used `&&` for logical AND.)

Comment: When clarifying things, it's a good idea to edit the question to add details and make corrections.  Those will be easier to read than a comment.

Comment: I'm not having any problems in the simulator or equivalent web code for the rules that you're saying are rejected.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is in the declaration of the constant uid. Very silly mistake. Apologies and thanks.